# Deleting all lines in text file until you get to a word vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Very new to vb.net, apologies if this is basic. I am trying to open up a text file and delete all the lines starting at index 0 until I hit the line that has the word I am looking for. Right now, it just deletes the word I put in it.

```
        ' Read the file line by line
        Using reader As New IO.StreamReader(fileName)
            While Not reader.EndOfStream()
                Dim input As String = reader.ReadLine()

                'Delete all lines up to String
                Dim i As Integer
                i = 0
                For i = 0 To input.Contains("{MyWord}")
                    builder.AppendLine(input)
                Next

            End While
        End Using
```

Comment: The following may be helpful: [File.ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.8) and [File.WriteAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Read the original file. Loop through each line (see [For...Next Statement (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement)). Save desired data to a string variable (see [Concatenation Operators in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/concatenation-operators)). Write desired data to file ([File.WriteAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.8))

Comment: Thank you, I will look into those resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial.  You didn't say what to do with the rest of the lines...

Did you mean lines?

```
    Dim ShouldRead as Boolean
    Dim builder As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Using reader As New IO.StreamReader(fileName)
        'Delete all lines without String
        While Not reader.EndOfStream()
            Dim input As String = reader.ReadLine()
            If input.Contains("{MyWord}") Then ShouldRead = True
            If ShouldRead Then
                builder.AppendLine(input)                    
            End If
        End While
    End Using
```

Comment: I did mean lines, apologies. Once I delete all the lines before {MyWord}, all of the other lines after can stay. I ran your snippet, it clears out all lines that don't contain {MyWord}. I would like to delete all lines before {MyWord} and after the word (only shows up one time), the lines can stay as they were.

Comment: Try now with the `ShouldRead` boolean set.

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to do it like this:

```vb
Dim lines = File.ReadLines(filePath).
                 SkipWhile(Function(line) Not line.Contains(word)).
                 ToArray()

File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lines)
```

The `File.ReadLines` method reads the lines of the file one by one and exposes them for processing as they are read. That's in contrast to the `File.ReadAllLines` method, which reads all the lines of the file and returns them in an array, at which case you can do as desired with that array.

The `SkipWhile` method will skip the items in a list while the specified condition is `True` and expose the rest of the list, so that code will skip lines while they don't contain the specified `word` and return the rest, which are then pushed into an array and returned. That array is then written back over the original file.

Just note that `String.Contains` is case-sensitive. If you're using .NET Core 2.1 or later then there is a case-insensitive overload but older versions would require the use of `String.IndexOf` for case-insensitivity.